# find ordering in two R vector

Tags: r, vector

If I have a character vector `a`,

```
a <- c("bob","jim","joe","fred")
```

and I have another character vector `b`, with the same elements but in a different order,

```
b <- c("joe", "jim", "fred", "bob")
```

is there a function that tells what element of `a` each element of `b` equates to? In other words, I would like a function that would return `c(3,2,4,1)` (because `b` is equivalent to  `c(a[3], a[2], a[4], a[1])`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `match(b, a)` .